Python: Selenium's driver.find_element(...) cant find the button im looking for:
This code is supposed to click a button (accept the cookies) and then take a screenshot of the page. It takes the screenshot of the right element with the right height & width, but it does not click the button before doing it.
The cookie button im talking about is the one on "u.gg": <button class="fc-button fc-cta-consent fc-primary-button" role="button" aria-label="Consent" tabindex="0">
I also tried clicking the buttons by coordinates, but i couldnt find the right ones.
The main question is: How do I tell Python to click that button?
This image shows the button with the green Consent button i want to click()
enter image description here
Im also open to other solutions like cookieblockers.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


url = "https://u.gg/lol/champions/kayle/build"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        
service = Service("chromedriver.exe") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

try:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2) 

    button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"fc-button fc-cta-consent fc-primary-button")
    element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"champion-recommended-build")

    button.click
    time.sleep(2)

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    time.sleep(2)  


    screenshot_path = "uggscreenshot.png"
    driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
    print(f"Screenshot saved to {screenshot_path}")
finally:
    driver.quit()


PS: I tried extending the time.sleep() time to give it more time (+ 3 Sec) and i watched the procces by disabling --headless, and it still doesnt find the button

button.click as written in the code is effectively a noop

OMG I HATE MY LIFE button.click is a function its missing () im sitting here for 4 hours (i woke up at 0:30)
Final code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


url = "https://u.gg/lol/champions/nunu/build"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
        
service = Service("chromedriver.exe") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

try:
    driver.get(url)
 

    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.fc-button.fc-cta-consent.fc-primary-button"))
    )
    button.click()

    time.sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"champion-recommended-build")

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    time.sleep(2)  


    screenshot_path = "uggscreenshot.png"
    driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
    print(f"Screenshot saved to {screenshot_path}")
finally:
    driver.quit()

